How can I remove the dropdown menu from always on display?
I am still a newbie and I created a navigation bar for a website using html and css, the services tab has a dropdown list, but the list stays on display even if display is set to none. Can anyone please assist me in this problem. I have tried many things now and can't seem to fix the problem. I added the code i used:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Navigation Bar with Dropdown</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a1b9a, #2e7d32);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .navbar ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .navbar li {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: color 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      color: #d1c4e9;
    }
    /* Dropdown Menu */
    
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
      /* Hidden by default */
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #6a1b9a;
      border-radius: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      z-index: 1000;
      width: max-content;
    }
    
    .dropdown li {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown a {
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #4a148c;
    }
    
    .navbar li:hover>.dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>



I have watched some videos on youtube and tried some existing code, but each time I try it with my own navbar, there is an issue.

The style for .navbar ul is targetting the .dropdown element you're trying to hide and has display: flex set. .navbar ul has a higher specificity, so it overrides the style from .dropdown.
To fix this, you can change the style selector from .navbar ul to .navbar > ul. By adding the >, you are saying "Select ul elements that are directly within the .navbar element", rather than selecting any nested children matching ul.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Navigation Bar with Dropdown</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a1b9a, #2e7d32);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .navbar > ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .navbar li {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: color 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      color: #d1c4e9;
    }
    /* Dropdown Menu */
    
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
      /* Hidden by default */
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #6a1b9a;
      border-radius: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      z-index: 1000;
      width: max-content;
    }
    
    .dropdown li {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown a {
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #4a148c;
    }
    
    .navbar li:hover>.dropdown {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>




The simple way, you just change class in your CSS
from .dropdown -> to .navbar .dropdown
code:


 (before):
       
       .dropdown {
          display: none;
          /* Hidden by default */
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #6a1b9a;
          border-radius: 8px;
          overflow: hidden;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          z-index: 1000;
          width: max-content;
        }

    ----------------------------------------------

      (after):
       .navbar .dropdown {
          display: none;
          /* Hidden by default */
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #6a1b9a;
          border-radius: 8px;
          overflow: hidden;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          z-index: 1000;
          width: max-content;
        }
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>



